# How to remove chrome icon add to home screen prompt

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am working with PWA app and I have an issue with add to home screen prompt. I need to remove the chrome badge from the app icon underneath.

Here is my **manifest.json**

```
{
  "short_name": "App Name",
  "name": "App Name",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "...",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "...",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "...",
      "sizes": "64x64",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/login",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#ffc107",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Your PWA passes all Lightroom tests and is a valid PWA? You are hosting your site on an HTTPS site? When you select "Add To Home Screen" form a site where you cannot answer yes to both of those questions, you see the badge.

Comment: @Mathias *Lightroom tests and is a valid PWA* **yes**... *You are hosting your site on an HTTPS site* **No it is on http**... And there is no question been asked during the add to home screen prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTPS is not optional for a PWA

All HTTP sites have the Add To Home Screen (A2HS) option in the menu
When those are installed, they have the added chrome badge on the icon

When HTTPS (and a valid PWA), you should also see the automatic Chrome A2HS prompt
And the installed PWA icon will NOT have the chrome badge added to it

If you want to test this, there are free HTTPS hosts like Glitch

my test
[image]

Comment: If it's not too private share the URL and I can check it. Also, run the Lighthouse tests on your HTTPS site to look for errors.

Comment: Installs fine without the chrome badge on your Icon. On Android & Chrome. You probably just need to clear out the cache and fully uninstall and previous tests.

Comment: are you saying that if the site has an ssl certificate and uses the https protocol, that it won't have the chrome icon on the pwa icon anymore?

Comment: my site is certifies and uses https and still the google chrome icon appears

Comment: @chs242 have a ink to the site you can share? I'll see what it does when I try it. It should not have the Chrome icon on your installed desktop. If you cannot share with me, have someone you know try who has never used that link before.